# Why mankind was mentioned twice apart from others?

Tags: genesis

What is the difference between Gen:1:27 and Gen:2:22?

> Gen 1:27 - So God created man in His own image, in the image of God He
> created him; male and female He created them.

> Gen 2:22 - And the LORD God fashioned into a woman the rib which He
> had taken from the man, and brought her to the man.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the site tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: You will need to make the question more explicit - what differences are you seeking?  Gen 2 simply gives more detail about the process that was only outline in Gen 1.  What else are you seeking?

Answer (score 0):

There are plainly two distinct Creation accounts at the opening of Genesis; they have different orders of events and more that set them apart.  As far as the creation of humans, traditionally there are a couple of views:

1. The man -- ha adam -- in Genesis 1 is a generic statement; in Genesis 2 more detail is given
2. In Genesis 1 mankind was created just as the animals were; in Genesis 2 a specific creation of specific individuals is related
3. In Genesis 1 the race of mankind is created in the regular world while in Genesis 2 a special pair apart from the rest is created in a special place (the Garden)

Given the distinct differences between the two accounts, and the explicit mention of God planting a garden, #3 seems the best choice.